# What is the boilerplate for using MySQL JDBC from a Tomcat servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I want to connect to a MySQL database using JDBC from my Tomcat servlet

This is what I tried:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://DatabaseURL",
                "username", "password");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        String sqlQuery = "use db name;";
        statement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
```

I imported in eclipse the JDBC and put it in the src folder.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: -1 for not posting the error message

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/",
                "root", "");

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();`

```
    String sqlQuery = "use onlinebidding;"; //databasename is onlinebidding
    statement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
```

Just compiled this code, its working perfectly.